# Set primary graphics on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce, sli

Same problem as:

[How can I determine and set my primary graphics card?](https://superuser.com/questions/330568/how-can-i-determine-and-set-my-primary-graphics-card?newreg=bbc950c975984bf0811edba594117e08)

Just with MSI EX630(9100M + 9300M GS); Windows 7 64-bit; nVidia 331.82 drivers;

When I connect external display(Samsung XL2370), I can't set it to work on 9300 anyhow. Even when I'm installing drivers for XL2370, I can only install for '9100M graphic adapter'.

And I'm pretty sure that 9300 is not used on demand, as in games that display used graphics adapter, I can see that the used adapter is 'nVidia 9100M'. Framerate also stutter (http://postimg.org/image/54dqq34cd/)

So I don't have the option in the nVidia Control Panel from the solution above.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I've just run 3dMark '06 to be sure that 9300m GS is not being used, and I'm sure now. http://www.3dmark.com/3dm06/17512534 My 3DMark Score is 1107.0 where 9300m GS average is about 1900 (http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-9300M-GS.9452.0.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using installing the 258.96 drivers (they are the latest with the Hybrid SLI support).

Comment: Your solution doesn't make sense.  If you already had 331.82 drivers installed they should have already had the required Hybrid SLI support your hardware requires.

Comment: Well, actually they don't.

Comment: You installed an older version the current drivers have hybrid support.

Comment: http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/258.96/258.96_Win7_WinVista_Desktop_Release_Notes.pdf "Driver version 258.96 will be the last driver to support Hybrid Power, a Hybrid SLI technology. Hybrid Power is supported on GeForce 9800 GX2 and GeForce 9800 GTX GPUs." Even my display adapter items from the device manager changed, not showing separate cards anymore. Not to mention 3dMark06 score, which is now 2566.