# Which VGA was used when i have 2 VGA attach to my PC?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga

Just some short question here. I have 2 VGA card attached for my 2 monitor, let said VGA 1 & VGA 2. VGA 1 was connected to monitor A & VGA 2 connected to monitor B.

If i play game and displayed on Monitor A, which VGA was used ? Only VGA 1 ?

and if i dragged the game window while the game still running to Monitor B, its automatically using VGA 2 to processing game graphic ? and not using VGA 1 anymore ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of VGA cards you use.

For simple 2D stuff, the VGA card that the monitor is attached to will be used to display the stuff. Actual processing is done using the drivers, and the drivers will find the VGA card that has this capability.

If you have 2 identical cards with crossfire (or otherwise bridged) they will both be used to calculate the graphics.

If you don't, you have to specify which card is the primary card. This can be done in the BIOS, but the videocard's drivers may also have this option.

See also: [How can I determine and set my primary graphics card?](https://superuser.com/questions/330568/how-can-i-determine-and-set-my-primary-graphics-card)