# Correct graphics card is not being used

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon

I just bought [this notebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JB3N6KS) and I am having trouble switching between which graphics card a game uses. It comes with an AMD Radeon HD8530M and Intel HD Graphics Family.

I went into "Configure Switchable Graphics" in the context menu and set the games to "High Performance", but they still end up using the Intel GPU. I have updated the AMD drivers but can't find any for the Intel one. Here's a screenshot of the names in Device Manager:

[image]

For example, when I run the benchmark for Super Street Fighter 4, it says I'm using the Intel GPU.

I want to use the AMD GPU when I play games. Any help would be appreciated!

Here are the BIOS and driver versions:

- BIOS version: 2.15.1236
- Intel driver: 10.18.10.3355
- AMD driver: 13.152.1.1000

Comment: Related: [How can I determine and set my primary graphics card?](http://superuser.com/questions/330568/how-can-i-determine-and-set-my-primary-graphics-card). I was under the impression there was an already heavy-voted question regarding this topic, but found none relevant. Long story short, it seems there are options in the BIOS and in the graphics' card configuration that enable the dedicated graphic board.

Comment: I checked the BIOS, and it only shows the Intel gpu.

Comment: Which BIOS version are you on? What's the AMD/Intel driver version? What happens if you manually disable the Intel graphic card from the Device Manager?

Comment: I added the versions in OP. When I disable the Intel card from device manager, I cannot use the AMD card. I try to open AMD Catalyst Control Panel, but I get an error saying it cannot be opened.

Also, I went ahead and replaced the generic AMD drivers with the ones provided from ASUS.

Comment: @cress, my BIOS doesn't show the other card too, but I can still choose to disable the integrated video card or use the PCI-Express one.

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu, can you tell me where to look in the BIOS? I go under "Advanced>Graphic Options" and the only thing I see under is the option to change "DMVT-PreAllocated" for Intel gpu.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpZr2khbPWQ#t=380) suggests having a look at **Devices & Peripherals** > **Video & Other Devices**.

Comment: I don't think I have that option in my BIOS. At least, I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the AMD Catalyst Center, go to the `switchable Graphic Application settings`, click on `Add application` and select the exe of the game and set it to high performance.

Now download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon HD to the gadget. if the GPU is not used you see this:

[image]

If the GPU is used you see this:

[image]

Is your AMD card now used? Or is still the Intel HD used?

Comment: The Intel HD doesn't even show up in that program but the AMD gpu does. I'm guessing the AMD gpu is in use since values change when I start up a game. How come the Intel gpu doesn't show up?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.1 seems to have problems with switching GPUs sometimes. 
I'd recommend installing the latest drivers for everything graphics-related but I see you already did/tried that. Usually the OEM (in you case Asus) should provide up-to-date drivers for the installed hardware but they often take their sweet time to release updates.
I read that a VBIOS update might work but again: if Asus has not released an update, then there is little to be done.

I "solved" this problem once by forcing the computer to only use the discrete GPU but unfortulately I can't remember how I did that now. I hope at least I could steer you in the right direction.

If I remember, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Should I use the AMD drivers Asus provides even if they are not the latest ones? The ones on AMD's website are much more recent.

Comment: @cress The AMD website can only provide *generic* drivers, which may not be compatible.