# Dual graphic card issue on Samsung laptop

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, amd-catalyst

So I have a laptop with two graphic cards on it - **Intel Graphic HD 4000** and **ATI Radeon 7670M**. I do know how to "*force*" programs to use ATI Card by using the *Catalyst Control Center* but this "magic switch" don't always work. Some programs even when forced will just run on Intel. This goes especially for games.

For instance **The Sims 2** will show on log that **Intel** graphic is used even after changing settings on Catalyst Center. Which is more confusing for me - games which allow to setup graphic before run (like **Deus Ex: Human Revolution**) don't recognize the ATI card. They just don't see it.

So I want to ask if this is *normal* and is there any way to **force** software to see the ATI card?

I am using Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: The simplest way.  Don't install the Intel drivers and/or disable it in Bios.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct graphics card is not being used](http://superuser.com/questions/774838/correct-graphics-card-is-not-being-used)

Comment: @Ramhound I tried to disable it in Bios - I can't. There is no option for it.

Comment: @Infero93 - I actually provided two ways.  The simplest solution to avoid having both GPUs be used is to NOT have drivers that support switching between the two devices installed.  This can be acomplished by not using the OEM drivers and instead use the AMD/Nvidia released drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound Will try to remove drivers for Intel